# XA transactions for ActiveMQ in python

Tags: python-3.x, activemq-classic, distributed-transactions

We want to have a distributed transaction publishing between two ActiveMQ brokers. The [ActiveMQ documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/should-i-use-xa) states they support XA transactions. Our code base is currently written in python. We have not found many examples of orchestration of xa transactions with ActiveMQ. We are currently using using [transaction package](https://pypi.org/project/transaction/) for transaction management. We are using the [stomp package](https://pypi.org/project/stomp.py/) to establish a connection. Does anyone have any reference on how to setup XA transactions to publish messages in python?

Answer (score 1):

The STOMP specification doesn't provide any means of performing XA scoped transactions so you are unlikely to find any reliable means of participating in such a transaction from a STOMP client and any broker implementation would be specific to that broker and not be portable to others.  The ActiveMQ 5.x broker supports XA transaction for the ActiveMQ JMS client which uses the Openwire protocol and does not implement XA support for STOMP or other protocols like MQTT or AMQP.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Since Stomp is not viable for our needs, are you aware of another python client that leverages openwire protocol?

Comment: I am not aware of any no, I'd doubt anyone is investing time into creating a python openwire client and even if they did I doubt they'd invest further time in adding in the complex support needed for XA as I don't think many folks would be using it

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want XA when you want to publish between two ActiveMQ brokers? The publication can be retried and finally succeed.
I think what you need is OutBox pattern, not XA.